# Why does the JTextArea disappear when I switch tabs?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

Why does the JTextArea disappear when I switch tabs? I'm running Ubuntu linux, if that makes a difference at all.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class LogView extends JPanel {

    private JLabel titleLabel;
    private TextArea orderViewArea;

    public LogView() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        titleLabel = new JLabel("Logging Information");
        // titleLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        String[] tempstuff = { "Active", "ALL", "Stuff" };
        JComboBox stageList = new JComboBox(tempstuff);
        stageList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JComboBox otherList = new JComboBox(tempstuff);
        otherList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JLabel dateStart = new JLabel("Date Start:   ");
        JLabel dateEnd = new JLabel("Date End:   ");

        JTextField dateStartField = new JTextField(9);
        JTextField dateEndField = new JTextField(9);

        JPanel datePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        datePanel.add(dateStart);
        datePanel.add(dateStartField);
        datePanel.add(dateEnd);
        datePanel.add(dateEndField);

        List s = new ArrayList();
        s.add("test1");
        s.add("test2");
        JList orderJList = new JList();
        orderJList.setListData(s.toArray());
        orderJList
                .setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        orderViewArea = new TextArea();
        orderViewArea.setEditable(false);
        orderViewArea.setText("Log stuff:\n Pizza\n Rochester\n stuff");

        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(titleLabel, constraints);

        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(stageList, constraints);

        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(datePanel, constraints);


        /*
        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(otherList, constraints);
*/
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainPanel.add(orderJList, constraints);

        //otherList.setVisible(false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(orderViewArea);
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 2;
        constraints.ipady = 5;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainPanel.add(scroll, constraints);

        add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame test = new JFrame("TEST");
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        tabs.addTab("test", new LogView());
        tabs.addTab("Test3", new JPanel());
        test.add(tabs);
        test.pack();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod  Same on Windows.  OTOH the code is mixing Swing & AWT components, so if I were to flip a coin and start making WAGs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix Swing with AWT components.  The 'start on EDT' still needs fixing, but try this code and report back.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LogView extends JPanel {

    private JLabel titleLabel;
    private JTextArea orderViewArea;

    public LogView() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        titleLabel = new JLabel("Logging Information");
        // titleLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        String[] tempstuff = { "Active", "ALL", "Stuff" };
        JComboBox stageList = new JComboBox(tempstuff);
        stageList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JComboBox otherList = new JComboBox(tempstuff);
        otherList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JLabel dateStart = new JLabel("Date Start:   ");
        JLabel dateEnd = new JLabel("Date End:   ");

        JTextField dateStartField = new JTextField(9);
        JTextField dateEndField = new JTextField(9);

        JPanel datePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        datePanel.add(dateStart);
        datePanel.add(dateStartField);
        datePanel.add(dateEnd);
        datePanel.add(dateEndField);

        List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.add("test1");
        s.add("test2");
        JList orderJList = new JList();
        orderJList.setListData(s.toArray());
        orderJList
                .setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        orderViewArea = new JTextArea();
        orderViewArea.setEditable(false);
        orderViewArea.setText("Log stuff:\n Pizza\n Rochester\n stuff");

        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(titleLabel, constraints);

        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(stageList, constraints);

        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(datePanel, constraints);


        /*
        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(otherList, constraints);
*/
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainPanel.add(orderJList, constraints);

        //otherList.setVisible(false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(orderViewArea);
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 2;
        constraints.ipady = 5;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        mainPanel.add(scroll, constraints);

        add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame test = new JFrame("TEST");
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        tabs.addTab("test", new LogView());
        tabs.addTab("Test3", new JPanel());
        test.add(tabs);
        test.pack();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: @trashgod  One of the first things I'll do with an SSCCE is to completely remove the AWT imports and see what breaks.  If there are only one or two from the package, I'll add back in just those.  I guess I've seen that problem too often.  ;)  To the OP.  Glad you got it sorted.  Good question, BTW - happy to help.  :-)